# Hide command output of parallel commands until first one ist finished

Tags: bash, zsh

For updating my system I have the following alias:

```
alias up="flatpak update -y & sudo dnf upgrade -y"
```

I deliberately chose `&` instead of `&&` to update both in parallel and save time.

The problem is that the terminal output is not useable because the two processes override each other's output.

Is it possible for one of the commands to hold back its output until the first one is finished?

Comment: `output=$(mycommand 2>&1); echo "$output"`?

Comment: In addition to the suggestion given by _Fravadona_, you may consider  running the background program via `nohup`, just in case you accidentally terminate your shell before it is finished.

Comment: Like this @Fravadona `flatpak update -y & output=$(sudo dnf upgrade -y 2>&1); echo "$output"`?

Answer (score 0):

If you have GNU `parallel` installed, you can do :

```
alias up="printf '%s\n' 'flatpak update -y' 'sudo dnf upgrade -y' | parallel"
```

Comment: It is not installed and I would prefer to not have additional dependencies :/
It also doesnt work btw. For updating TUIs just trash gets printed.

Comment: If you do `output=$(sudo dnf upgrade -y 2>&1); echo "$output"`, you would have trash printed as well.

Comment: Yes :D Until now I havent found a good solution